# Django on Heroku won't let me create a superuser

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've deployed a django app on to heroku. This app works perfectly running locally. However when I try to create a superuser on the heroku app so that I can access the admin page things aren't working. I've run:

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

And it appears to work. I get the prompt to choose a password, email and username. It then states:

```
Superuser created successfully.
```

However when I try to logon in the admin panel the username password combo fails. When I try to change the password of the account through:

```
heroku run python manage.py changepassword admin
```

I get:

```
CommandError: user 'admin' does not exist
```

Evidently heroku never actually created a supersuer. I'm at my wits end here, I don't understand what's wrong with the heroku dyno.

Comment: I haven't used Heroku before but my guess is, did you try restarting your server (Nginx, Apache, whatever it is) and then try logging in? Maybe the server needs to be restarted. Also, if you do "python manage.py shell", can you see the 'adim' user? Lastly, when logging in, just make sure you aren't accidentally using an email when it asks you for the username, or vise-versa.

Comment: Provided that your settings are correct for production not local, you can simply register admin as normal user, then get to the shell and escalate to superuser.

Comment: Apparently I had forgotten to uncomment a line in my settings.py file and the developement sqlite database was being pushed to the server. Then the server was happily working from that but wouldn't register new rows in the tables. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What line did you uncommented? Running on the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Just running `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser` worked for me. But @Nils , I want to know which line in the `settings.py` file you had to tweak to make it work for production.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a fuse system base database like sqlite.

As you know, [Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted):

> Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy

This is the reason why create user sun's successfully but, on next command (changing passed) the user is not there.

I write this answer mostly for future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To check what's going on, try running the following line twice:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

On a good setup, the first time will run the migrations, and the second time will say "No migrations to apply".  If you see it run the same migrations both times, this means that your database in Heroku didn't persist from one call to the next, and you need to change your database setup, for example by [connecting a postgres database](https://medium.com/@hdsingh13/deploying-django-app-on-heroku-with-postgres-as-backend-b2f3194e8a43).